# Monitoring network usage of individual applications?

Tags: macos, software-recommendation, utilities, monitoring

I want to monitor each application's network/internet usage on my Mac.

Sort of like how Activity Indicator shows total upload/download usage -- but I also want to know particular application usages.

Is this possible?

Comment: @koiyu What do you need that the existing answers don't provide?

Comment: @KyleCronin It's not that the existing answers wouldn't work – I was merely interested if there were more alternatives.

Answer (score 7):

The app [Little Snitch](http://www.obdev.at/products/littlesnitch/index.html) can do this. Among many other things, it shows traffic by app.

It costs $29, but there is a free trial available.

Answer (score 7):

Another app I've used is [RubbertNet](https://web.archive.org/web/20150321060332/http://rubbernetapp.com/) (site is down, linked via archive.org).  Also not free, but has a free trial available.

Answer (score 5):

A combination of

## **[HandsOff!](http://www.metakine.com/products/handsoff/)** and **[SurplusMeter](http://www.skoobysoft.com/utilities/utilities.html)**

is my current solution. HandsOff is an advanced firewall which similar to LittleSnitch. It's not free, but a trial version is available. Surplusmeter on the other hand is free and open source.

Among the features which you need for monitoring network usage are:

- monitoring network activity of every process (HandsOff!)
- get the network usage of individual processes (HandsOff!)
- log total network usage (SurplusMeter)

HandOff does only display the network usage since boot. It does not log the data which is why I need SurplusMeter. However, SurplusMeter only logs the total network usage for all applications.

[image] [image]

Comment: Sadly SurplusMeter has been discontinued :(

Answer (score 5):

Apple include a customised version of `tcpdump` as part of MacOS/OSX which allows for the display/filtering of packet capture metadata information - which contains a number of items (see man page excerpt below) and includes process information. e.g. so you could run it to capture traffic only from firefox (`-Q proc=firefox`) and print out all packet metadata information (`-k`):

```
sudo tcpdump -Q proc=firefox -k
```

Or you could run it with just the -k option(s) and extract and analyse data per process name/pid. For more details see `man tcpdump` - here's the relevant sections (though there's more in the man page about the PKTAP filters):

```
  -k Control  the  display  of packet metadata via an optional metadata_arg argument.
     This is useful when displaying packet saved in the pcap-ng file format  or  with
     interfaces that support the PKTAP data link type.

     By default, when the metadata_arg optional argument is not specified, any avail-
     able packet metadata information is printed out.

     The metadata_arg argument controls  the  display  of  specific  packet  metadata
     information  using  a  flag  word, where each character corresponds to a type of
     packet metadata as follows:

                 I     interface name (or interface ID)
                 N     process name
                 P     process ID
                 S     service class
                 D     direction
                 C     comment
                 C     flags
                 U     process UUID (not shown by default)
                 A     display all types of metadata

     This is an Apple modification.

   -Q expression
     To  specify a filter expression based on packet metadata information like inter-
     face or process name.  Packet with matching packet metadata will be displayed or
     saved  to  a  file.  See section PACKET METADATA FILTER for the syntax of packet
     metadata filter expressions.  This is an Apple addition.
```

Answer (score 1):

You could look at [WireShark](http://www.wireshark.org/).  It may have a daunting interface, but once you learn it, you can track traffic by port.

You can also check out the built-in terminal utilities [NetStat](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/netstat.1.html), [TCPDump](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/tcpdump.1.html) and [PCap](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man3/pcap.3pcap.html).

Using `netstat -t -u` will display the send and receive queue by process name.

Answer (score -1):

If you are using iOS 5+ you can use the [remote virtual interface](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1176/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS10001707-CH1-SECRVI)

```
$ # First get the current list of interfaces.

$ ifconfig -l

lo0 gif0 stf0 en0 en1 p2p0 fw0 ppp0 utun0

$ # Then run the tool with the UDID of the device.

$ rvictl -s 74bd53c647548234ddcef0ee3abee616005051ed



Starting device 74bd53c647548234ddcef0ee3abee616005051ed [SUCCEEDED]



$ # Get the list of interfaces again, and you can see the new virtual

$ # network interface, rvi0, added by the previous command.

$ ifconfig -l

lo0 gif0 stf0 en0 en1 p2p0 fw0 ppp0 utun0 rvi0
```

You should be able to use wireshark or tcpdump, or ngrep on the problem, via the mac.

EDIT: ipfw is deprecated, but you can just turn on logging and see which packets go where. I don't know how to do that with pf :(

EDIT: I don't know why I thought this was for iOS. Apologies

Comment: Truly interesting—but won't help me monitor the network usage of an OS X app on OS X.